# Sound attenuation for web browser

Tags: audio, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I have built a web browser in my project and put it on a wall. So the thing that I wanted to do is when I play a video on YouTube then I walk away from that wall I want the sound of that video to decrease depending on the distance.

I am looking in forums for days still can't find a solution for my problem. I have checked documentations in UE4 web page about attenuation and audio still couldn't found anything. I have found a video in internet but it shows only the result not how to do it. I'll be appreciated if you help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping the components in a blueprint? If not try;

"If you create a blueprint from your mesh, add a media sound component (add your media-player to this) and then tick 'Allow Spatialization' and 'Override Attenuation', this seems to make the sound localized to the mesh."

Most of the complaints I saw online regarding this question stem from the origin of the sound component Remaining at 0,0,0 world coordinates. Be aware of sound attenuations relative/world location toggle (Should be RELATIVE to the mesh and at the same location in the BP, and be a child of the mesh).

Answer (score 0):

From what I was told from an Epic employee.  This is an experimental plugin that was given up on.  There is no viable method for containing sound attenuations to the Web browser and the streamed source.  IE playing a YouTube video the sound will be 100% and no chance of adjusting it.

Thoughts come to mind of complex traces and setting volume to 0 if player is out of range set by the trace.  I have looked at so many ways of fixing this problem and given up many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it with C++. Unreal Engine uses Chromium Embedded Framework to display web content. I'm not sure about what CEF version was used for older UE, but for UE 5.2.1 and higher you can implement an audio handler with CEF. Usually you have to modify the engine for this, but personally I couldn't afford that so I just copied the WebBrowser module in my ueproject, renamed the module and some headers that caused some errors. I then implemented CefAudioHandler from cef_audio_handler.h in FCEFBrowserHandler (original file Engine/Source/Runtime/WebBrowser/Private/CEF/CEFBrowserHandler.h). CefAudioHandler gives PCM data (read more [here](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/master/include/cef_audio_handler.h)). I fed that data to a USoundWaveProcedural with the according conversions and then I simply played it with an AudioComponent which can then be assigned sound attenuation options.

I had only one issue which seems to be known, the CefAudioHandler doesn't kick in instantly so there's a short time in which you still hear the browser's audio directly to your audio output but I fixed that by muting the browser in FCEFBrowserHandler's OnAfterCreated with Browser->GetHost()->SetAudioMuted(true)